# Domain configured on Heroku with PointDNS but resulting in 403

Tags: heroku, dns, pointdns

I configured my domain with Heroku and PointDNS but when trying it, `deepdao.world`, or `www.deepdao.world`, the result is

`403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

This is my PointDNS setup:

[image]

The domain works with `heroku.deepdao.world`, but not without `heroku`. What am I missing?

EDIT: screenshots of my setup in `domain.com`: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you domain is not configured to use pointDNS name servers : https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/deepdao.world

Comment: @DusanBajic How do I fix this? Is there a clear manual? Should I go to domain.com, and set which parameters? Or is it something to change on PointDNS?

Comment: Go to domain.com and change nameservers to those that you can see as NS records in your PointDNS (dns12.pointhq.com, ...)

Comment: Keep in mind that that might beak other stuff (like email for your domain, your other subdomains if you have them ...) if your pointDNS records differ from existing domain.com records

Comment: also, you should probably remove that `*.deepdao.world` CNAME record

Comment: Looks like everything is set now, but still the link doesn't work. https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#ANY/deepdao.world

Comment: Was your name registered at doman.com? If not, you have to go to your domian registrar and make that same NS change

Comment: And if you did register your domain name there, check if there are separate NS settings in the site area where domain name registrations are handled.

Comment: I added screenshots of my entire setup in `domain.com`. It's still not working.

Comment: hm, it took some time for .world TLD name servers to be updated but it looks OK now, I can open http://deepdao.world/DaoSummary

Comment: `http://deepdao.world/DaoSummary` is not my site. is it hacked? `http://deepdao.world` is still not working.

Comment: Wait :). Is your site http://damp-depths-60854.herokuapp.com/DaoSummary or http://afternoon-beet-xi91pucszpz0epndkflwhrui.herokudns.com/ or none of those two?

Comment: `damp-depths...` is my app. The other link is the `herokudns` associated with it.

Comment: For me, http://deepdao.world/DaoSummary, http://heroku.deepdao.world/DaoSummary and http://damp-depths-60854.herokuapp.com/DaoSummary all show the same page.

Comment: Is it a page that has a header saying `Dao Analytics Insights for a decentralized world`? For me the deepdao.world/DaoSummary has 404, and the other two are good, with this header.

Comment: Not anymore, now it is 404 error; but I still have the other tab with page as it used to be https://imgur.com/a/H73fPSa

Comment: Works now, other than on one browser. Maybe a stubborn caching issue. Anyway thanks, do you want to create an answer based on the info above?

Comment: nah, it would be difficult to come up with anything useful for other users...

Comment: I think there's no one-to-one guide how to match all the different values. But your decision. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DusanBajic I'm still getting 404s on some browsers. Chrome on two different macs, and Opera on one mac (fine on another). Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Your previous NS values were cached with TTL value of 86400 seconds, which mean that old value could still be cached somewhere. There is pretty much nothing you can do about that now (and in the future, if you plan to make any DNS changes, make sure to lower the TTL vaues to minimum a day before). (still, on the same machine all browsers should show the same page).